# How to add a new property in document type

Tags: umbraco, umbraco8

I want add a new property in document type, it is a collection combine with external link & image such as facebook or google etc.

And I want to using it in template.

It is the example :

```
@foreach(var item in Model.imgCollection) {
    <a href="@item.ExternalUrl">
        <img src="@item.img" alt="">
    </a>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a nested content property editor. First create your Doctype that includes the image (Image picker) and the URL (Multi URL picker?) then create a new property with the Nested Content datatype and assign that doctype to the list of allowed types.